# Facebook4j - User properties null

Tags: java, facebook, oauth

I am trying to perform a user search using Facebook4j but all of the properties of the user objects are set to null (other than ID).

Code so far:

```
import facebook4j.Facebook;
import facebook4j.FacebookException;
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory;
import facebook4j.ResponseList;
import facebook4j.User;
import facebook4j.auth.AccessToken;
import facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class FacebookClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FacebookException {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();           
        cb.setOAuthAppId("...")
                .setOAuthAppSecret("...")

                /*A user access token with the following scopes: public_profile, basic_info,                      email, user_birthday, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_activities, user_interests, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_website, user_groups, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_about_me, user_status, user_games_activity, user_tagged_places, user_actions.music, user_actions.video, user_actions.news, user_actions.books*/
                .setOAuthAccessToken("");

        FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(cb.build());
        Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance();

        ResponseList<User> results = facebook.searchUsers("John Smith");

        for (User user : results) {
            System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
            System.out.println(user.getBirthday());
            System.out.println(user.getId());
            System.out.println(user.getRelationshipStatus());
        }

    }

}
```

The result of which looks like this for each User object:

```
null null
null
111111111111111 //A different ID per object 
null
```

Is there a permission configuration I need to adjust to retrieve the other user information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `out.println(facebook.toString())` to see if you have a valid instance. It may be because you are trying this from static main.